# How to query against a large list of words with an IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

I need to write a query that searches several fields in a table against a large list of words (about 50 words).  My current idea is to simply write an `IN` clause to put all of my words in.  However, creating this `IN` clause could become tedious due to the amount of words I have to search against.

Is there a better way of doing this?

My current query looks something like the following:

```
SELECT
x,
y
FROM Table1
WHERE 
x IN ('word1', 'word2', ... , 'wordx')
OR y IN ('word1', 'word2', ... , 'wordx')
```

Comment: Put the words in a table and join against it.

Comment: Why not put all the words into a table and join on them?

Comment: `select x, y from Table1 where x='word%' or y='word%';`

Comment: @deanosaur - I doubt the poster meant that all words *start with* **word**.

Comment: If the writing of the words is the hardest just write a script or a program to create the sql statement for you.  Put all the words in an array and create the SQL string programatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a table (let's say `word_table`) and store all your words inside it.
Then you can simply do

```
SELECT x, y
FROM Table1
WHERE 
   x IN (SELECT word FROM word_table) OR
   y IN (SELECT word FROM word_table)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
select t.*
from your_table t
left join word_table wx on wx.word = t.x
left join word_table wy on wy.word = t.y
where wx.word is not null 
   or wy.word is not null
```

Comment: with proper indexing this is probably a way faster method than the currently accepted answer.

Comment: Yes.  However, for my current task, I don't really need to consider speed.  But, still, I will consider your solution in future situations should I need to consider speed.

Comment: Is there a good reason to waste performance? Even if you don't need it to be fast it is way more economic to always consider speed if it does not cost money or time.

Comment: This is a very ad hoc problem that I'm working on.  It won't be repeated in the future.

Comment: I suggest also if ad hoc operation to use Table Variable in SQL Server: DECLARE @data TABLE
(column_1 DATATYPE, 
 column_2 DATATYPE, 
 column_N DATATYPE
)

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the usage of a word_table. My preferred method would be EXISTS.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM your_table
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM word_table WHERE t.x=word OR t.y=word)
```